# Powershell counting files on network location, different output when running Powershell vs the ISE

Tags: powershell, foreach, scripting

I am working on a Powershell script to count the number of files in each sub-directory for 2 Network paths. The script I have works great when I run it in ISE Debug but when I try to run it Powershell the output is truncated and it doesn't provide a count. I am pretty sure it is due to me closing the foreach in the wrong location but I can't seem to figure this out. I am very new to Powershell.

```
$dirs = "\\myserver\myshare\directory1" , "\\myserver\myshare\directory2"
$txt = "\\myserver\myshare\output.txt"

ForEach ($dir in $dirs)
    {
    (Get-ChildItem $dirs -recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object{
      $props = @{
         Folder = $_.FullName
         Count = (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.Fullname -File | Measure-    Object).Count
                }
New-Object PSObject -Property $props } | Select-Object Folder , Count) |   Format-Table -AutoSize | Out-File $txt
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Get-ChildItem should be $dir not $dirs
2. Your Format-Table should include the field names.

> ```
> $dirs = "\\myserver\myshare\directory1", "\\myserver\myshare\directory2"
> $txt = "\\myserver\myshare\output.txt"
>
> ForEach ($dir in $dirs)
> {
>     (Get-ChildItem $dir -recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object {
>       $props = @{
>          Folder = $_.FullName
>          Count = (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.Fullname -File | Measure-Object).Count
>                 }
> New-Object PSObject -Property $props } | Select-Object Folder, Count) | Format-Table -AutoSize -property Folder, Count | Out-File $txt
> }
> ```

I believe #2 is because Format-Table is assuming the width of your PS window to be maximum line width.  If the ISE window is full screen then the width of the PS window is larger than the default setting of the standalone PS window.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I now have this working. I still had to use Get-ChildItem $Dirs, by using Dir it only wrote one of the paths into the csv file. I did however use the Format-Table per your suggestion but I changed the -Autosize to a -wrap.

```
$dirs= ""\\myserver\myshare\directory1","\\myserver\myshare\directory2"                                                                                                           
$txt = "\\myserver\myshare\output.txt"

ForEach ($dir in $dirs)
{
(Get-ChildItem $dirs -recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object {
  $props = @{
     Folder = $_.FullName
     Count = (Get-ChildItem -Path $_.Fullname -File | Measure-Object).Count
            }
New-Object PSObject -Property $props } | Select-Object Folder, Count) |Format-Table -Wrap -property Folder, Count | Out-File $txt
}
```